# How do I create a fade in effect on my click to call button using gsap scrolltrigger?

Tags: javascript, gsap

```
/* CONTACT BUTTON */
.contact-button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: rgb(39, 152, 116, 0.7);
  background-color: rgba(39, 152, 116, 0.75);
  color: rgba(255, 249, 249, 0.776);
}

.contact-button:hover {
  border: rgb(29, 112, 86);
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(29, 112, 86);
}


// Creating the ScrollTrigger for Click-to-Call Button

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const callButton = document.querySelector(".contact-button");

ScrollTrigger.create({
  trigger: callButton,
  start: "#help, top",
  endTrigger: "#signup",
  end: "top top",
});
```

I am creating a website and recently added a click to call button that has a fixed position. I dont want the  button to appear on my homepage though but I want it to appear as soon as a user scrolls past the homepage.

I added both the gsap and scrolltrigger scripts to my html document and then registered the plugin in my script file before writing code that was supposed to create the desired effect. On save, nothing happened and I'm looking for help to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a gsap tween somewhere for the Scrolltrigger to call?

Also, you need some content to scroll past before the scrolltrigger element shows up.
Here's one solution - https://codepen.io/geedix/pen/ZEjrqXX
`gsap.to(".contact-button", {opacity:1, scrollTrigger:"#signup"})`